# Why is the enclosed charge in a Gaussian pillbox $\sigma A$ and not $2\sigma A$?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

From Gauss' Law,
$$
\oint \vec E\cdot\mathrm d\vec A=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}
$$

We draw a wafer-thin Gaussian pillbox extending just barely over the edge in each direction of conductor. But why we did we take the enclosed charge to be $\sigma A$ instead of $2\sigma A$ - shouldn't it be the total charge above *and* below?

Comment: why do you think that there's charge above and below the surface? The surface itself is the charge.

Comment: [Example 4.2: Infinite Plane of Charge - page 4.9](https://web.mit.edu/8.02t/www/802TEAL3D/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide04.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically we assume the sheet is infinitely thin and $\sigma$ is the charge per unit area of this sheet.

In a real sheet there would be a finite thickness and if it was a conducting sheet the charge would be concentrated on the upper and lower surfaces as you say. However we still mean $\sigma$ to mean the charge per unit area of the whole sheet. Or putting this another way, the charge density for just the upper surface is $\tfrac12\sigma$ and the charge density for just the lower surface is also $\tfrac12\sigma$. Then if we take a pillbox that encloses an area $A$ the charge enclosed is $\tfrac12\sigma A + \tfrac12\sigma A = \sigma A$.